# Windows Mobile - .NET CF: How to connect to the internet via PC?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I'm wondering is it possible to develop a small application (C#, .NET Compact Framework, maybe using Windows Mobile SDK (I don't know yet)) which will be able to connect to the internet when my phone is connected to the PC. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

Sure.  Just [set up the PC connection to allow pass-through](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsmobile/archive/2006/11/20/wmdc-activesync-pass-through-feature.aspx).